# Next-Auth: how to return the response from the server to the client

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-auth

I am working on a mini project with `Next-Auth` (with credentials), I have the following scenario:

```js
const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'credentials',
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { email, password } = credentials as { email: string; password: string }
        const uuid = uuidv4()
        const res = await fetch("https://myapi.blabla/api/v9/accounts/sign-in/", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `uuid ${uuid}`,
            "Client-Id": "vrfyrvKmSIRs8s1BZuHcmHNaZuTR2nIF0ZgFt39",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password
          })
        })

        const user = await res.json()

        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error(user.message)
        }

        // If no error and we have user data, return it
        if (res.ok && user) {
          return user
        }

        // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
        return null
      }
    })
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login'
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token }) => {
      return token
    },
    session({ session, user }) {
      return { ...session, ...user }
    },
  }
}
```

If I console.log `const user = await res.json()` the response is:

```js
{
   "advertising_id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "api_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "username": "xxxxxxx",
   "session": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

The problem is, when I use `const session = useSession()` in the front, I only get:

```js
{
  session: {
    user: {
      name: undefined,
      email: 'micorreo@gmail.com',
      image: undefined,
    },
    expires: '2023-04-09T14:53:56.395Z'
  }
}
```

And I need the response should be something like:

```
{
  session: {
    user: {
      name: undefined,
      email: 'micorreo@gmail.com',
      image: undefined,
      session: 'xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      advertising_id: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      etc...
    },
    expires: '2023-04-09T14:53:56.395Z'
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? Or do I need a different mechanism to be able to send the session information to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few missing things:

- When creating `CredentialsProvider` you should have passed

  ```
  session: {
     strategy: "jwt",
  },

  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  ```
- If inside authorize, you are returning `user`, that user will be passed to `jwt` callback

  ```
  jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
    user && (token.user = user);
    return Promise.resolve(token);
  },
  ```
- then this token will be passed to the `session` callback

  ```
  session: async ({ session, token }) => {  
      session.user = token.user;
      return Promise.resolve(session);
  },
  ```

You can see an [example setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71956621/next-auth-4-session-returns-null-next-js)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, that works perfect! My previous approach also worked for me:

```js
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user?.session) {
        token.session = user.session
      }

      if (user?.username) {
        token.username = user.username
      }
      
      return token
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      session.user.session = token.session
      session.user.username = token.username

      return session
    }
```